# Application not Installed issues Galaxy S3

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm having a strange issue with people running my application with a samsung galaxy s3, when they try to launch the application a toast appear saying : "Application not Installed".

this is the manifest for my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.pievis.gestureplayer"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" >
        <activity
            android:name="it.pievis.gestureplayer.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PlayListActivity" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabLayoutActivity" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".OptionsActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".EqualizerActivity" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".FavPlaylistActivity" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Do you know what the issue could be? Thanks for helping me

Comment: Is the app in the play market? Which app? If not, can I download it? Have you tried on a Galaxy S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with a duplicate user-permission.